# Spotify snap package can't open "error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2"

Tags: snap, spotify

error:

```
/snap/spotify/57/usr/bin/spotify: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9):

A workaround is to use the apt version of spotify instead of the snap version.

First remove the snap version. Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo snap remove spotify
```

The next part of this answer is based on the [official instructions](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/).

Now add the public key.

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_5E3C45D7B312C643.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now add the repository.

```
echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Update the software index.

```
sudo apt update
```

Install spotify.

```
sudo apt install spotify-client
```